# WordPress - make first image my Feature Image

Tags: php, wordpress

I use PHP to create new posts in WP using wp_insert_post();

I wanna ask if there's ever a way to make the first image the Feature Image of this post.

FYI : the first image is NOT stored on the server, it's stored externally..

I really need your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [featured image page of the WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/). You'd have to do something like make a plugin or make/modify a theme to use it.

It seems that it is expected for featured images to always be added via the `media library`. I'm sure it would be possible to do the same thing with an external image, but you'd have to make your plugin bypass the WordPress system.

To get the first image in a post you can do something like this within a plugin...

```
function your_function_name($content) {

        /** $content is a string and is the post content **/
        /** Here you can use strstr or preg_match to find the first
            occurence of an image in the post content. For example,
            this will print the matches at the end of the blog post.
            Once you have the first image you can do whatever you want with it..  **/

    $pattern = '/src="(.*\.(jpg|jpeg))"/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
    $content .= var_dump($matches);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'your_function_name');
```

This is a filter so it runs every time a post is displayed on the blog. If you wanted to do something one-time-only you would do it a different way.

If anyone knows a better/simpler way than this I would also be very interested.